# Plotly Set custom tickvals for all points but do not show all ticks

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

The illustration on "Tickmode Array" on the help [page](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/) shows the issue.

[image]

If we hover on x=1, the hover label will show "(**One**, 28.8)". But if we hover on x=2, the hover label will show "(**2**, 28.5)". This is because tickvals and ticktext are set for x=1 but not x=2.

I'd like to show "(**Two**, 28.8)" **AND** keep the gridline as-is ("One", "Three", ...). Adding x=2 setting in tickvals and ticktext won't do because it will add a new gridline x=2.

How can this be done?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    y = [28.8, 28.5, 37, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9]
))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
        ticktext = ['One', 'Three', 'Five', 'Seven', 'Nine', 'Eleven']
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your code sample as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    y = [28.8, 28.5, 37, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9],
    text = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve'],
    hovertemplate = 'X:%{text}<br>Y:%{y:.2f}<extra></extra>'
))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
        ticktext = ['One', 'Three', 'Five', 'Seven', 'Nine', 'Eleven']
    )
)


fig.show()
```